# Unitary representation compact Lie Groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group. I have to prove that for $n$ large I there is an immersion of $G$ in the unitary group $U(n)$. I know that any finite-dimensional representation of a compact Lie group is unitary and thus completely reducible. So I have to prove that this representation is faithful... right?

Answer (score 7):

You need to prove that you group $G$ has a faithful representation.   This "is" Peter-Weyl theorem (or a corollary of, depending on how one states things).